# How to display an altered version of textarea input in another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

How could I create a new html div (not another input box) that displays an edited version of text from a textarea using javascript?

I would like the edited version to replace the word "red" with "r". Would there be a way of updating the edited div every time the user enters more text into the textbox? Here is my textarea.

```
<!--text box-->
<form name=sentence>
<textarea class="sentencebox" id="sentence" placeholder="Enter the sentence here." wrap="soft" style="width:300px; resize:none; border:none;">
</textarea><br>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance, and bonus kudos if someone could come up with a way of making the new "r" appear in red!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure JS or jQuery for that, here is [quick example - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8x6S/)

```
$('#sentence').on('keyup',function(){

    // here you can update your div
    $('#myDiv').text($('#sentence').val());
});
```

and to replace 'red' with 'r'

```
$('#sentence').val().replace('red','r')
```

Comment: if put it in a `<pre>` tag will display  line breaks also